# creating a gradebook using structures and ifstream

Tags: c++

Okay, so I have to write a program that, when the user enters `"load filename"` where `"filename"` is symbolic of the file you want to open (`"input.txt"` for example). This will read in all the data and store the students' names, grades, and computes the average. Then, the user can enter `"display filename"` which will display the students' last name, first name, and all of their scores on attendance, homework, projects, midterm, and final. The input file will always have the same first 5 lines with them looking like this:

```
    Attendance: 5
    Midterm: 20
    Final: 20
    Homework: 15
    Projects: 40
    Henry, Patrick
    Attendance: 12 15
    Midterm: 80 100
    Homework: 50 100
    Homework: 60 100
    Homework: 80 100
    Project: 90 100
    Project: 80 100
    Project: 75 100
    Final: 80 100
```

The first number is what the student received and the second is what they could have possibly scored. Homework and projects will always be out of 100 points however, you don't know how many of each you'll have. You will, however, have one of every other category. The last category is always final and it may or may not be followed by another student. There will be no more than 100 students. I have written this code:

```
int main()
{
    int numStudents = 0;
    int projCount = 0;
    int hwCount = 0;
    student students[100];
    string command, filename;
    cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
    cin >> command;
    ifstream in ;
    cin >> filename;
    string Attendance, Midterm, Final, Homework, Projects;
    int A, M, F, H, P;
    while (!in.fail())
    {
        if (command == "Load"
         || command == "load"
         || command == "l")
        {
            in .open(filename);

            in >> Attendance >> A
               >> Midterm >> M 
               >> Final >> F
               >> Homework >> H
               >> Projects >> P;

            string lname, fname;
            in.ignore(200, '\n');
            getline(in, lname, ',');
            getline(in, fname, '\n');

            while (!in.fail())
            {
                string cat;
                int score, possible;
                in >> cat;
                in >> score >> possible;
                while (cat != "Final:")
                {
                    students[numStudents].last = lname;
                    students[numStudents].first = fname;
                    if (cat == "Attendance:")
                    {
                        students[numStudents].attendpos = possible;
                        students[numStudents].attendgot = score;
                        students[numStudents].attgrade = (score * A) / possible;
                    }
                    else if (cat == "Midterm:")
                    {
                        students[numStudents].midpos = possible;
                        students[numStudents].midgot = score;
                        students[numStudents].midgrade = (score * M) / possible;
                    }
                    else if (cat == "Homework:")
                    {
                        students[numStudents].hw[hwCount] = score;
                        hwCount++;
                        students[numStudents].hwgrade = (score * H) / 100;
                    }
                    else if (cat == "Project:")
                    {
                        students[numStudents].proj[projCount] = score;
                        projCount++;
                        students[numStudents].projgrade = (score * P) / 100;
                    }
                    in >> cat; in >> score >> possible;
                }
                in >> score >> possible;
                students[numStudents].finpos = possible;
                students[numStudents].fingot = score;
                students[numStudents].fingrade = (score * F) / possible;
                students[numStudents].average = students[numStudents].fingrade + students[numStudents].hwgrade + students[numStudents].projgrade + students[numStudents].attgrade + students[numStudents].midgrade;
                numStudents++; in .ignore(200, '\n');
                getline(in, lname, ',');
                getline(in, fname, '\n');
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
            {
                cout << students[i].average << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (command == "Display" || command == "display" || command == "d")
        {
            cout << "Displayed:  " << filename << endl;
            cout << "#Students:" << numStudents << endl;
            cout << "Last Name" << "   First Name" << "   Attendance";
            for (int i = 0; i < hwCount; i++)
            {
                cout << "HW" << i << "   ";
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < projCount; i++)
            {
                cout << "Proj" << i << "   ";
            }
            cout << "   Midterm";
            cout << "   Final" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
            {
                cout << students[i].last << " " << students[i].first << " " << students[i].attendgot;
                int j = 0;
                while (j < numStudents)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < hwCount; i++)
                    {
                        cout << students[j].hw[hwCount] << "   ";
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < projCount; i++)
                    {
                        cout << students[i].proj[projCount] << "   ";
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                cout << students[i].midgot << "   " << students[i].fingot << "   " << students[i].average << endl;

            }
        }
        else if (command == "Sort" || command == "sort" || command == "s")
        {
            cout << "A" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "I didn't recognize that" << endl; in >> command;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my header file:

```
struct student
{
    string last;
    string first;
    double attgrade;
    double midgrade;
    double hwgrade;
    double projgrade;
    double fingrade;
    int attendpos;
    int attendgot;
    int midpos;
    int midgot;
    int finpos;
    int fingot;
    int hw[20];
    int proj[20];
    double average;
};
```

The issue I'm having, however, is that the code stops running after you enter `"load filename"` and I don't know why. Also, I haven't finished the sort part so don't worry about that else if statement. I have all of the necessary libraries included. But, why is the program stopping after you type in the first command?

EDIT:
In addition the that issue, it also only stores one student's information for some reason. Please help me!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your code expects 'load' and the filename to be entered separately

Comment: You can enter it on the same line or on different lines

Comment: Debuggers are your friend. It would answer your question in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your program.
I suspect it's just not opening the desired input file.
Try adding the following after in.open(...

```
if(in.good())
{
cout << "file opened"<<endl;
}
else
{
cout << "file not opened"<<endl;
}
```

I compiled the following using msvc2008... and using the debugger, confirmed your expected program behaviour.

```
// test1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string last;
    string first;
    double attgrade;
    double midgrade;
    double hwgrade;
    double projgrade;
    double fingrade;
    int attendpos;
    int attendgot;
    int midpos;
    int midgot;
    int finpos;
    int fingot;
    int hw[20];
    int proj[20];
    double average;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int numStudents = 0;
    int projCount = 0;
    int hwCount = 0;
    student students[100];
    string command, filename;
    cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
    cin >> command;
    ifstream in ;
    cin >> filename;
    string Attendance, Midterm, Final, Homework, Projects;
    int A, M, F, H, P;
    while (! in .fail())
    {
        if (command == "Load" || command == "load" || command == "l")
        { in.open(filename.c_str()); 
        if(in.good())
        {
                cout << "file opened"<<endl;
        }
                    else 
                    {
                    cout << "file opened"<<endl;
                    }
          in >> Attendance ;
          in >> A ;
          in >> Midterm >> M >> Final >> F >> Homework >> H >> Projects >> P;
            string lname, fname; in .ignore(200, '\n');
            getline( in , lname, ',');
            getline( in , fname, '\n');
            while (! in .fail())
            {
                string cat;
                int score, possible; in >> cat; in >> score >> possible;
                while (cat != "Final:")
                {
                    students[numStudents].last = lname;
                    students[numStudents].first = fname;
                    if (cat == "Attendance:")
                    {
                        students[numStudents].attendpos = possible;
                        students[numStudents].attendgot = score;
                        students[numStudents].attgrade = (score * A) / possible;
                    }
                    else if (cat == "Midterm:")
                    {
                        students[numStudents].midpos = possible;
                        students[numStudents].midgot = score;
                        students[numStudents].midgrade = (score * M) / possible;
                    }
                    else if (cat == "Homework:")
                    {
                        students[numStudents].hw[hwCount] = score;
                        hwCount++;
                        students[numStudents].hwgrade = (score * H) / 100;
                    }
                    else if (cat == "Project:")
                    {
                        students[numStudents].proj[projCount] = score;
                        projCount++;
                        students[numStudents].projgrade = (score * P) / 100;
                    } in >> cat; in >> score >> possible;
                } in >> score >> possible;
                students[numStudents].finpos = possible;
                students[numStudents].fingot = score;
                students[numStudents].fingrade = (score * F) / possible;
                students[numStudents].average = students[numStudents].fingrade + students[numStudents].hwgrade + students[numStudents].projgrade + students[numStudents].attgrade + students[numStudents].midgrade;
                numStudents++; in .ignore(200, '\n');
                getline( in , lname, ',');
                getline( in , fname, '\n');
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
            {
                cout << students[i].average << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (command == "Display" || command == "display" || command == "d")
        {
            cout << "Displayed:  " << filename << endl;
            cout << "#Students:" << numStudents << endl;
            cout << "Last Name" << "   First Name" << "   Attendance";
            for (int i = 0; i < hwCount; i++)
            {
                cout << "HW" << i << "   ";
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < projCount; i++)
            {
                cout << "Proj" << i << "   ";
            }
            cout << "   Midterm";
            cout << "   Final" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
            {
                cout << students[i].last << " " << students[i].first << " " << students[i].attendgot;
                int j = 0;
                while (j < numStudents)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < hwCount; i++)
                    {
                        cout << students[j].hw[hwCount] << "   ";
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < projCount; i++)
                    {
                        cout << students[i].proj[projCount] << "   ";
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                cout << students[i].midgot << "   " << students[i].fingot << "   " << students[i].average << endl;

            }
        }
        else if (command == "Sort" || command == "sort" || command == "s")
        {
            cout << "A" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "I didn't recognize that" << endl; in >> command;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It opens the correct file because it outputs the correct average. The program just stops running though for some reason